# make element have the height of it's parent element

Tags: css

I have a picture here to help me explain the problem I am having.

[image]

As you can see from the image, the `checkmark` is centered vertically for the one-lined `p` but when it gets to the two or three lined `p` then the checkmark is no longer vertically centered.

I'd ideally want the checkmark to have a height of 100% of the div, so that there is no text below it or above it... if that makes sense.

Here is my current code:

```
#container { //the individual div for each item
cursor:default;
}

#text { //id name for my paragraph tag.
cursor: auto;
font-size: 16px;
margin-right: 15px;
display: inline;
}

#checkmark{
padding-right: 10px;
height: 100%;
font-size: 16px;
z-index: 20;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Edit: Here is my html

```
<div id="container"><i id="checkmark" class="fa fa-check"></i><p id="text">Some text here....</p></div>
```

Comment: Post your HTML as well please. We need a complete code example.

Comment: @j08691 Sorry, added.

Comment: You may want to use a table since its layout aligns after dimensioning. Block elements suchs as `div` aren't exactly designed to align with height. It's still possible, but I don't see why a table would be bad here.

Comment: You may want to consider using a `<ul><li>` (unordered list) instead of `<div>`s, They have a natural indent on the `<li>` that will get the alignment you need.

Comment: True, if your use case is actually shown in the screenshot, use the `<ul>` (or `<ol>`) tag with `list-style-image`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `display: inline;` to `display: table-cell;` in both `#checkmark` and `#text` and add `vertical-align: middle;` to `#checkmark`, like this:

```
#text { //id name for my paragraph tag.
    cursor: auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: table-cell;
}

#checkmark{
    padding-right: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    z-index: 20;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Worked brilliantly. Thanks so much.